# Dynamically setting line-height/keeping text vertically centered when parent div changes size in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to achieve the following in HTML/Javascript:

- have a coloured circle with a piece of text perfectly centred (both horizontally and vertically) within it;
- dynamically from JavaScript, be able to alter the size of the circle, maintaining the text centred within it at all times.

The following achieves the first of these:

- Create the circle using a DIV element whose style has appropriate background and border-radius;
- Inside the DIV, put a P element whose style has "text-aligbn: center" and "line-height: ".

For example:

```
p.circlecaption {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 128px;
}
...
<div style="background: #a0a0a0; margin: 0px; width: 128px;
   height: 128px; border-radius: 64px;" id="theCircleDiv">
     <p class="circlecaption" id="theText">TEST!</p>
</div>
```

This works fine for the initial, static, case. The problem comes when, from JavaScript, I attempt to set the line-height property in order to keep the text vertically centred as I change the size of the div. I expected something like the following to work:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('theCircleDiv');
var sz = '' + (rad*2) + 'px';
obj.style.width = sz;
obj.style.height = sz;
obj.style.margin = '' + (64 - rad) + 'px';
obj = document.getElementById('theText');
obj.style['line-height'] = sz;
```

However, while this code re-sizes and re-centres the circle perfectly, it doesn't vertically re-centre the text-- i.e. the attempt to dynamically set line-height appears to be ignored.

Can anybody offer any help on either how to set line-height dynamically, or else a way to achieve my desired goal of keeping the text centred within the circle? From my reading around, I've seen various other suggestions such as calling the property "lineHeight" or playing around with "vertical-align: middle", but none seems to work.

(I am currently testing in Safari on Mac OS which is likely to be most used among the site's target audience, but am also looking for a solution that is reasonably cross-browser compatible.)

Comment: Here is an approach that worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HKByH/  but you didn't tag this question with jquery so I'm hesitant to submit it as an answer.

Comment: There, I took the jQuery out of the resizing (kept it in for the slider so you can see it work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/HKByH/2/).  I'm using jQuery UI to wire up some dynamic setting of the size but the re-size code should work in a pure JavaScript environment.

First, I cleaned up the HTML and put it's style in CSS

HTML:

```
<div id="theCircleDiv">
    <p class="circlecaption" id="theText">TEST!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#theText {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 128px;
}
#theCircleDiv {
    background: #a0a0a0;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border-radius: 64px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function resize(size) {
    var circle = document.getElementById('theCircleDiv'),
        text = document.getElementById('theText');
    circle.style.width = size + 'px';
    circle.style.height = size + 'px';
    circle.style.borderRadius = (size / 2) + 'px';

    text.style.lineHeight = size + 'px';
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? This is precisely one of the suggested options that doesn't work for me, testing in Safari.

Comment: Sorry, ignore last comment -- have just re-tested and it appears to work. There seems to be a slight issue where the text doesn't stay horizontally in exactly the same place, but it is basically working, thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that the circle itself should be centered inside a larger space?

Comment: Yes, basically the effect I'm trying to achieve is for the circle to "oscillate" in size, with the centre of both the text and the circle staying identical. The code I have -- changing the margin to compensate for the change in size -- along with your lineHeight modification, basically achieves this, just that -- in Safari at least -- the text doesn't remain in exactly the same place, I'm guess because of rounding errors in the calculated position. I guess I can get round this by using images instead of actual text in the worst case.

Comment: Here is a modified version that tries to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/HKByH/3/  It's untested on a broad swath of browsers though, so you'll have to decide if it works for you

Comment: Thanks -- FWIW, your test also exhibits the problem I was mentioning: that as you re-size the circle, the test stays in the same place *within a pixel or two* (presumably, within the accuracy of a pixel following its calculation of the location for a given size, which unfortunately does not resolve to the same place).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with pure css

```
#theCircleDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#theText {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bZj52/

Comment: Thanks -- this works, only it has a knock-on effect on the layout of surrounding components that may mean I can't use it.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, the `#theCircleDiv` maybe out of the layout because of `display: table-cell` try surrounding it in another div with floats, positions or whatever you use for layout

Comment: Yes, you're right - it's really just a practical issue of whether I have time to change the surrounding code within the available deadline. I think the solution you present is viable in principle.

Answer (score 3):

And this is much easier with flex box.

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  /* Important Part */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Center Me Please</span>
</div>
```